# ForEach loop values keeping previous values

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a foreach loop from which i am sending emails for my customers. 
I have 4 customers in my db 1,2,3,4
So according to foreach loop the loop will run for 4 times to send an email to every customer
But in 1st run it sends email to customer 1.
In 2nd run It is sending email to customer 1 and 2.
In thirdd run it is sending email to customer 1,2,3 and so on.

How can i make to send one email to one customer.
here is my code.

```
$list=$tmp_con->query("SELECT name,email FROM users WHERE user_type='$tp' AND subscribed='yes' AND verified='1'") or die($tmp_con->error);
    $lis=array();

while($row=$list->fetch_array()){
    $lis[] = $row;
}
foreach($lis as $lst){


         $content = str_replace("{name}", $lst['name'], $mail_content);

         $content=$content."".$append_unsub;

         /**************************************************phpmailer class***********************/

                //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

                $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
                $mail->Host = $mail_smtp_host;  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username = $mail_smtp_username;                 // SMTP username
                $mail->Password = $mail_smtp_password;                           // SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = $mail_smtp_enc;                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
                $mail->Port = $mail_smtp_port;                                    // TCP port to connect to

                $mail->setFrom($mail_smtp_from_email, $mail_smtp_from_name);
                $mail->addAddress($lst['email']);     // Add a recipient

                $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

                $mail->Subject = $mail_subject;
                $mail->Body    = $content;


                if(!$mail->send()) {
                    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } else {
                    echo 'Message has been sent';
                }
            $lst['email']='';            
         /*************************************************php mailer ends here*************************************/


    } ///foreach ends here
```

Comment: please use var_dump oder similar to create debug output, what is inside the $mail object and inside $lst['email'] on each loop call

Comment: Base your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). It's much more efficient than what you have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `$mail` object in the loop or even better reset the addresses in the loop. You've (probably) declared the `$mail` object outside the for loop.

So every time you call `addAddress` you're adding the email address of the user. The first time you're setting the email address of the first user, then the second time you're adding the email address to the list, so two email addresses. Third round the same, fourth round etc..

**Edit**: Creating `$mail` inside the loop fixes the problem, but isn't efficient. See Synchro's comment for a better way to create and send the email.

Comment: Yes the mail objecct was outside the loop. Its working fine after placing the mail object in the loop. Thanks

Comment: Don't create the PHPMailer instance inside the loop - it's inefficient and you don't need to do it to solve this problem. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

No need of creating an instance of PHPMailer in each and every loop. Use `$mail->clearAddresses();` at the end of foreach loop to clear all the addresses.

***Updated Code***

```
$list = $tmp_con->query("SELECT name,email FROM users WHERE user_type='$tp' AND subscribed='yes' AND verified='1'") or die($tmp_con->error);
$lis = array();

while ($row = $list->fetch_array()) {
  $lis[] = $row;
}

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = $mail_smtp_host;  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = $mail_smtp_username;                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = $mail_smtp_password;                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = $mail_smtp_enc;                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = $mail_smtp_port;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$mail->setFrom($mail_smtp_from_email, $mail_smtp_from_name);

foreach ($lis as $lst) {
  $content = str_replace("{name}", $lst['name'], $mail_content);
  $content = $content . "" . $append_unsub;

  //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;  
  $mail->addAddress($lst['email']);     // Add a recipient
  $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
  $mail->Subject = $mail_subject;
  $mail->Body = $content;

  if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
  }
  $mail->clearAddresses(); // Clear all addresses for next loop
}
```

**References:**

1. [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps)